# Use ArrayList in Activity as content for RecyclerView Adapter in frament

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, static, android-recyclerview

I have this `Activity` inside of which there are two fragments in a TabLayout.

In my `Activity` there is an static `ArrayList`.
I'm my fist `Fragment`, let's call it `FragmentOne` I have one `RecyclerView` and the second `Fragment`, `FragmentTwo` i where I need the magic to happen.

In `FragmentTwo`, I'm calling that same `ArrayList` from my `Activity` and adding one or more items to it. In `FragmentOne` I'm also calling the same `ArrayList` and passing it's value to a non static `ArrayList`, the one that is used in my `RecyclerView`'s adapter.

How I can call the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` of my `FragmentOne`'s `RecyclerView` in my second `Fragment`, so the `RecyclerView` would update it's content?

Or there is a more efficient way of sending the item to my fist `Fragment` `ArrayList` that I use in my `RecyclerView Adapter`?

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    FragmentOne fragmentone;

    // The ArrayList used as FragmentOne RecyclerView's Adapter
    public static ArrayList<Contacts> contactsArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();

        contactsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    }

}
```

FragmentOne RecyclerView:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    // RecyclerView's adapter
    ContactsAdapter ctcAdapter;

    // RecyclerView
    RecyclerView rvContacts;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        // RecyclerView
        rvContacts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        // Here I'm adding the static list from the Main Activity in the adapter
        ctcAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getContext(), MainActivity.contactsArrayList);

        rvContacts.setAdapter(ctcAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The only thing I need is how to call the `ctcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in my second fragment, after I add a new Item to the `contactsArrayList` to make the list in the firs fragment show the added item.

Comment: It would be better if you posted a snippet of the code of interest. That would explain better than trying to explain in prose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  One way would be to make `FragmentOne` implement a listener.  Something like:

```
public interface ContactsChangedListener {
   void onContactsChanged();
}

public class FragmentOne implements ContactsChangedListener ... {
   ...
   @Override
   void onContactsChanged() {
     ctcAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

In `FragmentTwo`, provide a way to pass the listener:

```
public class FragmentTwo ... {
   ...
   private ContactsChangedListener mContactsChangedListener;
   ...
   public void setContactsChangedListener(
     ContactsChangedListener listener) {
     mContactsChangedListener = listener;
   }
}
```

And then, in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`, you can just pass the one to the other as an interface:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    ...
    fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
    fragmentTwo.setContactsChangedListener(fragmentOne);
    contactsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

It's nothing fancy.  But it does the trick, and it maintains encapsulation.